# How to Display a custom html page on 'New Item' button click in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view

I have an html page, which i need display when an user tries to add new item in a SharePoint List. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the steps for achieve your functionality.

- Edit New Item form
- Minimize default web part
- Add Content Editor Web Part and give your HTML page link in Content Editor Web Part property
- Save page

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Is there any other way? Actually It was one of the questions that asked me for an interview. He said there are more than 1 way to do it .

Comment: Yes, you can change list NewForm.aspx URL from SharePoint Designer. So you can change it from there and give your custom page URL.

Comment: okay, Sam got it.